# Typescript function returning jest test - what should return type be

Tags: typescript, jestjs

If I encapsulate a jest test in a function using TypeScript, what should be the expected return type? Thanks.

```
const foo:JestReturnType = () => test('this is a test', expect(true).toBeTruthy());
```

Comment: There are [published type definition files for jest](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/f104ec4ddf4a979321be38300a450cca71f5f567/types/jest)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `test` or `it` is `void`:

```js
const foo = (): void =>
  test('this is a test', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });

describe('test suites', () => {
  foo();
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58310060/index.spec.ts (10.251s)
  test suites
    ✓ this is a test (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.401s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58310060